# Animate sideways via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have a few `<div>` elements and a menu which is supposed to "call" these different `<div>`s on click with a custom animation.

These are the menus:

- Normal
- Remote
- Tools
- Register
- Log in
- Donate
- Contact
- Terms of use

Now I need to control and show different divs based on which menu entry I click.

I need help in two occasions:

1. Creating the animation (see the jsfiddle below)
2. Handling the transitions between the divs efficiently without lots of code rewriting.

**Occasion 1:**

When I click on a menu (*Remote* for example) I want the other visible menu to move itself to its complete *right* side and disappear (I've used `overflow: hidden` on the main div for that) and then from the *left* side the proper div to come in (*remote-page* div).

So basically, I'm wanting to make the slideDown and slideUp horizontal.

This is what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Dugi/UtH4m/8/

This is a good example to show what I've got already for my website locally. I failed to make the proper div come in from the **LEFT** side when a menu button was clicked, I just could make it so I can **HIDE** the divs that are standing on the way.

**Final question:** So how do I use *.animate()* to make the proper div come in from the left side AFTER the other visible div went to the right?

**Occasion 2:**

As you can see from the jsfiddle above, I had to go through each existing `<div>` and hide them:

```
$('#remote').click(function()
{
      $('#normal-page').animate({marginLeft: '100%'}, 'fast'); // here
      $('#tools-page').animate({marginLeft: '100%'}, 'fast');  // here   
});
```

**Final question:** Is there a way to automatize this process and hide all visible divs and show the proper one when a menu button is clicked?

This is all I want to know.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `complete` parameter of the animate function to achieve that. I took the liberty of changing HTML and CSS a bit if you do not mind.
http://jsfiddle.net/UtH4m/9/

Final version: http://jsfiddle.net/UtH4m/13/

Comment: for some reason I can't seem to get it to work on my website, which differs from the example, I thought I made them enough alike, but it seems I did not. May I show you my website's HTML?

Comment: Make sure to provide only relevant parts =)

Comment: The selector had to be changed to `"#inner > div"` to include only first level children of the `#inner` div. ( http://jsfiddle.net/UtH4m/11/ )

Comment: Now it works, thank you. But as I feared, there is a side effect as always in jQuery: From the jsfiddle you provided, click *Remote* and then click *Normal*, you can see that the `data-page="normal"` doesn't slide to the right, it simply disappears in place. Any way to fix this? The same is happening on my website, just like in the fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, just a small fix: current page should only become visible when it is about to slide in. http://jsfiddle.net/UtH4m/12/

Comment: AWESOMENESS! Thanks a lot. There is one last thing I noticed, please bear with me... When you are (for example) at the *Normal* page and click the *Normal* menu button again, it will remake the transition, even though it's not needed for the same page. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/UtH4m/13/ . Nothing special, just checking if current page is visible or hidden.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is what you want. I changed you markup a little bit. I added a `#container` for all the pages that is moved around. This is how it would look like: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ldaniell14260/UtH4m/10/)